# Rewrite rule exceeding internal redirect limit

Tags: .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting, friendly-url

I have up to four parameters to accept on my site so I've added the following to my .htaccess.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?atr=$1&dir=$2&query=$3&lookup=$4 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?atr=$1&dir=$2&query=$3 [L]
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)/([^/]*)$ /index.php?atr=$1&dir=$2 [L]

RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?atr=$1 [L]
```

All was working fine until I added the fifth line to allow only one parameter. This returns 500 errors in all instances of index.php with the error:

```
Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects
```

Comment: What was the 5th rule?

Comment: @hjpotter92 sorry I've made it slightly confusing, I'm referring to the fifth line, fourth rule.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens with your 4th rule is:

```
RewriteRule ^([^/]*)$ /index.php?atr=$1 [L]
```

this matches the redirected/rewritten URL as well. So, you get something like:

```
http://host/index.php?atr=index.php%3Fatr=index.php%3Fatr=index.php%3Fatr=index.php%3Fatr=index.php
```

which is the redirect loop. To resolve this, just use a pattern which negates matching `index.php` itself.

```
RewriteRule ^((?!index\.php)[^/]*)$ /index.php?atr=$1 [L]
```